# List a Joined table with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a 
Product entity with a list of warehouses with this partially code:

Product.java

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "product_has_warehouse", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = ID), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
        name = "warehouse_id"), foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK + "has_warehouse"),
           inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK + "warehouse"))
private List<Warehouse> warehouses;
```

So i need to make a criteria query to get the list of warehouses by product id.

I tried:

```
    final CriteriaQuery<Warehouse> query = getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Warehouse.class);
    final Root<Product> root = query.from(Product.class);
    final Join<Product, Warehouse> warehouseJoin = root.join("warehouses");


    query.where(getCriteriaBuilder().in(warehouseJoin));
    final TypedQuery<Warehouse> typedQuery = getEm().createQuery(query);

    return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

But i get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred validating the
>   Criteria Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No explicit
>   selection and an implicit one could not be determined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
     @Test
     public void getWarehousesByProduct() {

        Product drinks = new Product("drinks");

        Warehouse wh1 = new Warehouse("house1");
        Warehouse wh2 = new Warehouse("house2");
        Warehouse wh3 = new Warehouse("house3");
        Warehouse wh4 = new Warehouse("house4");
        Warehouse wh5 = new Warehouse("house5");
        Warehouse wh6 = new Warehouse("house6");

        drinks.getWarehouses().add(wh1);
        drinks.getWarehouses().add(wh2);
        drinks.getWarehouses().add(wh3);
        drinks.getWarehouses().add(wh4);

        saveAll(Arrays.asList(new Warehouse[]{wh1,wh2,wh3,wh4,wh5,wh6}));
        em.persist(drinks);

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Warehouse> cq = cb.createQuery(Warehouse.class);
        Root<Product> product = cq.from(Product.class);
        Join<Product, Warehouse> warehouses = product.join("warehouses");
        cq.select(warehouses).where(cb.equal(product.get("id"), drinks.getId()));

        TypedQuery<Warehouse> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
        List<Warehouse> result = tq.getResultList();

        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        Assert.assertEquals(drinks.getWarehouses().size(), result.size());
     }
```

Notice that i did only `"one directional"` way. Doing `bidirectional` way, you need to add product to it's feasible warehouses (to satisfy bidirectional condition). 
By the way, your mistake was missing `cq.select(warehouses)` that's why you got an illegal state because your query don't know what to select.